# How can I remove the "Test With" menu left after uninstalling TestDriven.NET?

Tags: tdd, testdriven.net

I have uninstalled my trial of TestDriven.NET but it leaves this menu behind on the context menu. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes for TestDriven.NET 2.19](http://www.testdriven.net/downloads/releasenotes.html) mention that this problem (issue 1631) was fixed in 2.19:

> 1631: After uninstalling TestDriven.Net, ghost 'Test With' menus are left behind
>   'Test With' menus will be deleted as part of the uninstallation process.

so I imagine you were running an earlier version.

Could you try downloading, installing, and uninstalling 2.19 to see if that gets rid of the ghost menu?

If that doesn't work, since it's acknowledged bug, perhaps you need to contact the author directly [here](http://www.testdriven.net/contact.aspx) or [here](http://www.testdriven.net/support.aspx).

Comment: You are probably right. Luckily I was testing on a virtual PC so I will roll it back.